# How to integrating Microsoft Teams with Blue Prism to automate message through Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, rpa, blueprism

I'm working on integrating Microsoft Teams with Blue Prism to automate messages through Teams. Got to know that I can use Microsoft Graph to do that but couldn't get the complete picture of it.

No idea how to integrating Microsoft Teams with Blue Prism to automate messages through Teams.

I would like to send a message to a Teams channel through blueprism. For example:

- Once the run completed inform to business via teams or
- if any business exception send a message to business.

If anyone can share their understanding / knowledge on this on how we can integrate, that would be great.

Comment: please add some more details, what you try to achieve, and also what you already tried.
Do you want to send messages from Blue Prism to Teams, or the other direction or both? Do you want to have a bot in Teams for controlling a 3rd party service or device?
A super simple way for a fixed setup of a Team is to send mails to a channel that get shown in teams, but is that sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Hi, Yes i would like to send message to teams channel through blueprism. For eg. Once the run completed inform to business via teams or if any business exception send a message to business.

Comment: I don't have knowledge about blueprism, so maybe the answer is obvious, but: how is Microsoft Graph related to your goal?